# How to predict target on a validation set with a Pipeline containing OneHotEncode and LightGBM?

Tags: scikit-learn, prediction, one-hot-encoding, lightgbm

I am trying to use sklearn and LightGBM with both numerical and categorical features. I created a Pipeline with:

- 1 step for data preprocessing relying on ColumnTransformer (categorical variables are encoded with OneHOtEncoder).
- 1 step for actual model training with LightGBM.

It trains my model just fine but I have an error message when I want to use my model for prediction on a test dataset. It looks like the preprocessing is not applied to this test dataset but I don't get why. In the tutorials I've found online, it seems to work, though with sklearn classifiers.

Here is my code:

```py
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer,
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Numerical features
numerical_features = ['Distance']
numerical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
     ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
     ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

# Categorical features
categorical_features = ['Travel', 'Month', 'DayofMonth', 'DayOfWeek', 'UniqueCarrier']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
     ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
     ('onehot', OneHotEncoder())])

# Build the preprocessor with ColumnTransformer
preprocess = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
                                                 ('num', numerical_transformer, numerical_features),
                                                 ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)
                                               ]
                                 )

# Build a pipeline
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocess', preprocess),
                      ('classifier', LGBMClassifier(random_state=17))])

# Fit
clf.fit(X_build, y_build)

# Scores
print("model training score (clf internal scoring function with standards parameters): {0}".format(clf.score(X_build, y_build))) # returns a score
print("Score: %f" % clf.score(X_valid, y_valid)) # Here is the problem
```

And here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-70bf0e236540> in <module>()
----> 1 print("Score: %f" % clf.predict(X_valid))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    116 
    117         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 118         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    119         # update the docstring of the returned function
    120         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    329         for name, transform in self.steps[:-1]:
    330             if transform is not None:
--> 331                 Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    332         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    333 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in transform(self, X)
    491 
    492         X = _check_X(X)
--> 493         Xs = self._fit_transform(X, None, _transform_one, fitted=True)
    494         self._validate_output(Xs)
    495 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    391                               _get_column(X, column), y, weight)
    392                 for _, trans, column, weight in self._iter(
--> 393                     fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True))
    394         except ValueError as e:
    395             if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    918                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    919 
--> 920             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    921                 pass
    922 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params)
    603 
    604 def _transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params):
--> 605     res = transformer.transform(X)
    606     # if we have a weight for this transformer, multiply output
    607     if weight is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _transform(self, X)
    449         for name, transform in self.steps:
    450             if transform is not None:
--> 451                 Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    452         return Xt
    453 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in transform(self, X)
    611                                        copy=True)
    612         else:
--> 613             return self._transform_new(X)
    614 
    615     def inverse_transform(self, X):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in _transform_new(self, X)
    572         n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    573 
--> 574         X_int, X_mask = self._transform(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)
    575 
    576         mask = X_mask.ravel()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in _transform(self, X, handle_unknown)
    105                     msg = ("Found unknown categories {0} in column {1}"
    106                            " during transform".format(diff, i))
--> 107                     raise ValueError(msg)
    108                 else:
    109                     # Set the problematic rows to an acceptable value and

ValueError: Found unknown categories ['BOS-CHS', 'ORD-JAC', 'LAS-OKC', 'VCT-IAH', 'CVG-EGE', 'PIT-PVD', 'BDL-SLC', 'TEX-PHX', 'LAX-LGA', 'LEX-LGA', 'CLE-SLC', 'KOA-SNA', 'SNA-HNL', 'MDW-SNA', 'MIA-SEA', 'MEM-RDU', 'YUM-IPL', 'SLC-KOA', 'EGE-EWR', 'MTJ-DFW', 'TPA-CHS', 'FLL-OAK', 'PVD-MCI', 'SLC-DSM', 'RSW-DEN', 'ORD-JAN', 'ATL-FSD', 'CHS-JAX', 'MCO-MLI', 'FSD-SLC', 'SLC-LGA', 'GRB-DFW', 'PNS-JAX', 'BDL-LAX', 'ATL-SOP', 'MSP-FAI', 'CLT-CAE', 'PIT-SEA', 'SRQ-IND', 'PHF-CLT', 'MIA-CMH', 'FAR-SLC', 'TUL-LAS', 'EWR-TUS', 'ORD-STT', 'CLT-TRI', 'BHM-CLE', 'ORD-PWM', 'SRQ-IAH', 'BOI-ORD', 'ATL-EGE', 'ATL-CID', 'IND-MSY', 'EGE-LAX', 'BUR-PDX', 'BTR-LGA', 'MIA-SLC', 'ONT-PDX', 'CLE-SBN', 'MSP-JAC', 'CMH-FLL', 'MEM-AUS', 'PHX-MFR', 'SJU-STL', 'ASE-SLC', 'CID-ATL', 'DFW-MLI', 'SCC-BRW', 'LGA-MSN', 'MCO-PFN', 'MDW-SJU', 'SEA-SIT', 'DTW-OMA', 'GRR-TPA', 'EGE-SFO', 'DFW-RST', 'GRR-LAS', 'TPA-TLH', 'PWM-CLT', 'TLH-MIA', 'PHF-FLL', 'SFO-EGE', 'SAT-STL', 'RSW-MKE', 'DTW-MSY', 'IAH-TXK', 'TLH-JFK', 'ATL-GUC', 'IAH-VCT', 'DEN-GRR', 'IND-SEA', 'PIE-MDW', 'BHM-IAD', 'IAD-BHM', 'BUR-MCO', 'MTJ-EWR', 'CLE-HOU', 'MSY-STL', 'DFW-SYR', 'BUF-LAS', 'LEX-EWR'] in column 0 during transform
```

Do you know what the problem is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that OHE finds new categories in the validation sample that were not there in the training sample.

Unfortunately, sklearn's implementation can not handle such situation out-of-the-box. So one has to check that categories in the new data are the same as in the training set. There can be different strategies on how to treat new categories. Try to google and experiment with different things. Examples can be: make OHE aware of all possible categories including those in the new data (using `categories` argument in the constructor) or drop those new categories in new data (compare new data to automatically learned `categories_` parameter). Of course, the first option does not make sense in production, but the second can be always implemented

Comment: Ok, I get it. Here I am just exploring data so I can also use the first solution. Maybe I'll have a look at how I generated my training and test sets, it's possible I didn't specify to keep the same proportions. Thanks a lot !